# Qt error is printed on the console; how to see where it originates from?

Tags: qt, error-handling, qml, qtquick2

I'm getting this on the console in a QML app:

```
QFont::setPointSizeF: Point size <= 0 (0.000000), must be greater than 0
```

The app is not crashing so I can't use the debugger to get a backtrace for the exception. How do I see where the error originates from?

Comment: What prevents you from doing a search for `setPointSizeF(` ?

Comment: @Murphy: First off, it's possible (and likely) that `setPointSize` (a C++ function) is not invoked directly by my code (which is mostly QML) but due to me assigning to the property `pointSize` of an object in QML. Then I could search the project for `pointSize` and that's actually what I first did. But I get too many matches (it's a biggish project) so I want a more exact way.

Comment: Ok, if you can't find a code generating the error for what did you create the issue? The warning is pretty clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the function the warning occurs in (in this case, [`QFont::setPointSizeF()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/text/qfont.cpp#n909)), you can put a breakpoint there. Following the stack trace will lead you to the code that calls that function.

If the warning doesn't include the name of the function and you have the source code available, use `git grep` with part of the warning to get an idea of where it comes from. This approach can be a bit of trial and error, as the code may span more than one line, etc, and so you might have to try different parts of the string.

If the warning doesn't include the name of the function, you don't have the source code available and/or you don't like the previous approach, use the [`QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html#warning-and-debugging-messages) environment variable:

```
QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN="%{function}: %{message}"
```

For the full list of variables at your disposal, see the [`qSetMessagePattern()` docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qSetMessagePattern):

- `%{appname}` -   QCoreApplication::applicationName()
- `%{category}` -  Logging category
- `%{file}` -  Path to source file
- `%{function}` -  Function
- `%{line}` -  Line in source file
- `%{message}` -   The actual message
- `%{pid}` -   QCoreApplication::applicationPid()
- `%{threadid}` -  The system-wide ID of current thread (if it can be obtained)
- `%{qthreadptr}` -    A pointer to the current QThread (result of QThread::currentThread())
- `%{type}` -  "debug", "warning", "critical" or "fatal"
- `%{time process}` -  time of the message, in seconds since the process started (the token "process" is literal)
- `%{time boot}` - the time of the message, in seconds since the system boot if that can be determined (the token "boot" is literal). If the time since boot could not be obtained, the output is indeterminate (see QElapsedTimer::msecsSinceReference()).
- `%{time [format]}` - system time when the message occurred, formatted by passing the format to QDateTime::toString(). If the format is not specified, the format of Qt::ISODate is used.
- `%{backtrace [depth=N] [separator="..."]}` - A backtrace with the number of frames specified by the optional depth parameter (defaults to 5), and separated by the optional separator parameter (defaults to "|"). This expansion is available only on some platforms (currently only platfoms using glibc). Names are only known for exported functions. If you want to see the name of every function in your application, use QMAKE_LFLAGS += -rdynamic. When reading backtraces, take into account that frames might be missing due to inlining or tail call optimization.

On an unrelated note, the `%{time [format]}` placeholder is quite useful to quickly "profile" code by `qDebug()`ing before and after it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [qInstallMessageHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) (Qt5) or [qInstallMsgHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler) (Qt4) to specify a callback which will intercept all `qDebug()` / `qInfo(`) / etc. messages (example code is in the link). Then you can just add a breakpoint in this callback function and get a nice callstack.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious, searching your code for calls to `setPointSize[F]`, you can try the following depending on your environment (which you didn't disclose):

1. If you have the debugging symbols of the Qt libs installed and are using a decent debugger, you can set a conditional breakpoint on the first line in `QFont::setPointSizeF()` with the condition set to `pointSize <= 0`. Even if conditional breakpoints don't work you should still be able to set one and step through every call until you've found the culprit.
2. On Linux there's the tool `ltrace` which displays all calls of a binary into shared libs, and I suppose there's something similar in the M$ VS toolbox. You can grep the output for calls to `setPointSize` directly, but of course this won't work for calls within the lib itself (which I guess could be the case when it handles the QML internally).